# Как загрузить файл на сервер через ajax (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

При использовании стандартных функций после отправки данных из инпута фал не записывается на сервер. Не пойму в чем дело, читал статьи, везде написано примерно одинаково. Но у меня что то по ним не работает.

Вот пример

- на стороне клиента:

```js
var militaryScan = $('.form-group.military input.file');
$('.sendapp').click(function() {
  var controller = $(this).attr('name');
  var fileMilitary = militaryScan[0].files[0];
  if (fileMilitary) {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', fileMilitary);
    $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      data: formData,
      url: "/user/" + controller,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      }
    })
  }
});
```

на сервере:

```
public function addAnketa() {
    $consfig['upload_path'] = "./assets/uploads";
    $consfig['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
    $this->load->library('upload', $consfig);
    if($this->upload->do_upload('file')){
        echo "Файл загружен";
    }else{
        echo "Файл не загружен";
    }       
}
```

вот так не работает и ошибок не выдает, просто в консоль выводится что файл не загружен.
 пробовал еще вот так

`$consfig['upload_path'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/application/assets/uploads/';`

Но когда пишу вместо этой функции стандартную такого вида, то все загружается

```
public function addAnketa() {
    $file = file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
    file_put_contents( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/application/assets/uploads/'.$_FILES['file']['name'], $file);
}
```

Comment: Если upload_path в конфиге полным указать?

Comment: дополнил вопрос. Пробовал писать еще и такой вариант в конфиге

Comment: Вроде бы по коду всё нормально. В CodeIgniter  лучше пути полные указывать, а также бывают проблемы с попредлением mime-типа. Попробуйте вообще его не указывать. Ещё могут быть проблемы с декодированием не-английских имен файлов, а также наличие в имени пробелов. То есть попробуйте с конфигом upload поиграть.

Comment: Забыл добавить. Библиотеку еще через initialize нужно инициализировать.

Comment: да! оказалось нужно было добавить initialize в инструкции было написано что этот метод требует только если наш config хранится в отдельном файле

Comment: Вот и хорошо. :-)